# Limiting Nlog internal log file size

Tags: logging, nlog

I've been tasked with finding a way to manage the internal log files nlog is generating for all of our projects. The files are continuously being appended to leading to very large files ~80 MB and up. After looking into the matter I came across [this issue on Nlog's GitHub](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/581#issuecomment-74923718) which specified that layout variables aren't usable on nlog's internal log files.

Is there any other possible method to handle the every growing internal log files that is built in to nlog?

**Edit:** Changing the internalLogFileLevel to Error from Warn greatly reduced the number of lines being written to our internalLogFiles.

Comment: It isn't expected that there are constantly warnings and errors are written. Is the source of those known?

Comment: Turns out we were exceeding our Rollbar warning limit and that was writing back to our logs.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no builtin file size limit.

A work around would be to disable writing the internal log to a file and use the [`InternalLogger.LogWriter`](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.3.0/html/P_NLog_Common_InternalLogger_LogWriter.htm).

Another option is to disabled the internalLogger (set it to `off`) and only enable it when there are issues.